# ruby (on rails): how to loop array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I have:

```
@layout = [:maincol => ['a'], :sidecol => []]
```

then I want to loop and get:

```
<div class="maincol"><div class="a"></a></div>
<div class="sidecol"></div>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Gareth and Totty must be a two-headed giant because how on earth would he know that was the output Totty was looking for?

Comment: @DJTripleThreat: The original was http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/df55e6d5-3781-4762-8538-76b2681751df/view-source

Comment: Totty had asked the complete question but had forgot to indent to cause the <pre> effect to kick-in. See the raw version of the first rev.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this is a ruby question not ruby-on-rails. Secondly there are a few **naming conventions** in Rails and `@layout` would certainly confuse other programmers as well as `:maincol` and `:sidecol` is a rather bad naming and they should be what ever the model behind is.

```
<div class="maincol"><% @layout[:maincol].each do |element| %>
   <%= "<div class="%s"></div>" % element %>
<% end %></div>
<div class="sidecol"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<% @layout.each |column| %>
  <%= column.each |outer,inner| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, inner.empty? ? {} : content_tag(:div, {}, :class=>inner), class => outer) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Assuming that you actually wanted a `div` tag in the inner loop, and the `</a>` in the question is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick way:

```
@layout = [{:maincol => ['a']}, {:sidecol => []}] # I'm assuming this was the explicit data structure you meant

html = @layout.map do |s|
  s.map do |k,v|
    contents = (v.map{|ss| content_tag('div', '', :class => ss)} unless v.empty?) || ''
    content_tag('div',  contents, :class => k)
  end
end.join('')
```

I think you should try a different arrangement for your @layout variable, if you want a tag inside another tag, what you really want to use is a [recursive data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursive_data_structures_.28structural_recursion.29).

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html

Check "each" method...